# Make \bibitemsep stretchy

Tags: spacing, biblatex

How do I make the space between bibitems (`\bibitemsep`) stretchy in order to have the whole text area filled, i.e. remove the space marked by the red arrow by stretching the space between the items?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}    

\begin{document}
        \nocite{*}
        \setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
        \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The bibliography is more or less a normal list, so standard list techniques (of which I know nothing, I found `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\fill}`, but that's a bit meh) should work.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your feedback! You brought me on the correct track: `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
        \addtolength{\bibitemsep}{\fill}` seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

biblatex issues a `\raggedbottom` at the begin of the bibliography. You can change this e.g. with etoolbox:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\bibsetup{\flushbottom}


\begin{document}
        \nocite{*}

        \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1) `etoolbox` need not be loaded explicitly, though. It might be worth quoting the original definition of `\newcommand*{\bibsetup}{%
  \interlinepenalty=5000\relax
  \widowpenalty=10000\relax
  \clubpenalty=10000\relax
  \raggedbottom
  \frenchspacing
  \biburlsetup}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your MWE works exactly how it should. However if I try to combine it with a larger spacing, e.g. `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}` I get many `Underfull \vbox` warnings and the same spacing as before. So the remaining question is, how to increase the spacing without setting `\bibitemsep` explicitly, as this seems to destroy your nice solution.

Comment: The default value of bibitemsep is `4.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt.`, which shows that it needs something stretch in it (but not a full \fill). Try something like `\setlength\bibitemsep{\dimexpr \baselineskip\relax plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Works like a charm! Thank you very much!